# ¿Como remplazar un caracter dentro de una cadena en una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, string, python-2.7

Tengo una lista que tiene varios elementos tipo string. Cada elemento de la lista tiene caracteres que no son deseados y se quieren quitar. Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente lista
`lista = ["cadena1.", "cadena2."]`
El caracter no deseado es : **"."** . Por lo tanto, ese caracter no lo quiero en ningun elemento de la lista. Mi lista deseada debe quedar asi:
`lista = ["cadena1", "cadena2"]`
Alguna ayuda? debo eliminar varios caracteres especiales, por lo tanto, se debe usar el código varias veces

Llevo el siguiente código:

```
hola = ["holamundoh","holah","holish"]
print(hola[0])
print(hola[0][0])
for i in range(0,len(hola),1):
  for j in range(0,len(hola[i]),1):
    if (hola[i][j] == "h"):
      hola[i] = hola[i].translate({ord('h'): None})
print(hola)
```

Pero al querer evaluar la expresion del if, siempre me salta el error : "string index out of range". Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Si los caracteres que deseas eliminar siempre están al inicio o al final puedes utilizar `lstrip` (Elimina caracteres al inicio) `rstrip` (Elimina caracteres al final) `strip` (Elimina caracteres al inicio y al final)

Con la lista `hola` que muestras en tu pregunta, estos serían los resultados

```
#lstrip()
['olamundoh', 'olah', 'olish']

#rstrip()
['holamundo', 'hola', 'holis']

#strip()
['olamundo', 'ola', 'olis']
```

Pero si la cadena tuviera alguna "h" intermedia entonces ninguno de los 3 métodos la eliminaría, por ejemplo la cadena `aloha` devolvería `aloha`con cualquiera de los 3 métodos mencionados anteriormente

Ejemplo completo con `rstrip()` (Puedes sustituir el método por `lstrip` o `strip` para probar el funcionamiento)

```
hola = ["holamundoh","holah","holish", "aloha"]

for i, v in enumerate(hola):
    v = v.rstrip('h')
    hola[i] = v
print(hola)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
['holamundo', 'hola', 'holis', 'aloha']
```

Si deseas realmente reemplazar todas las instancias de cualquier caracter o lista de caracteres, entonces puedes utilizar `replace()`

Ejemplo (Nota que la cuarta cadena tiene carateres intermedios)

```
reemplazar = ['.', ',', '-']
cadenas = ['cadena1.', 'cadena2,', 'cadena3-', 'c.a,d-ena4']

for i, v in enumerate(cadenas):
    for caracter in reemplazar:
        v = v.replace(caracter, '')
        cadenas[i] = v

print(cadenas)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
['cadena1', 'cadena2', 'cadena3', 'cadena4']
```